# Upload progress bar with Business Catalyst

Tags: progress-bar, business-catalyst

Can I implement a upload progress bar with Business Catalyst? I can not use any server-side language such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to fake it using jQuery or javascript. You cannot do a true progress bar in BC.

What I do is upon form submission (that contains a file upload), I fade in an animated gif or better yet, an icon that spins using CSS animations.